# Error while connecting to Flask server over Airflow and Docker

Tags: docker, flask, airflow, devops

I have created a Machine Learning model and exposed it to port 5000 using Airflow and Docker.

Here's the content of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest

USER airflow

COPY requirements.txt /
COPY ml-pipeline.py /

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" -r /requirements.txt
```

Here's the code for docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  sleek-airflow:
    image: pythonairflow:latest

    volumes:
      - ./airflow:/opt/airflow

    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

    command: airflow standalone
```

Here's the code for DAG file

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime
import requests


dag = DAG(
    'pipeline_dag',
    default_args={'start_date': days_ago(1)},
    schedule_interval='0 23 * * *',
    catchup=False
)

execute_script_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='execute_script',
    bash_command='python /ml-pipeline.py',  # Replace with the actual path to your script
    dag=dag,
)

execute_script_task
```

Here's the content for the ML pipeline

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

app = Flask(__name__)

# Step 1: Fetch the California housing dataset
data = fetch_california_housing()

# Step 2: Split the data into features (X) and target (y)
X = data.data
y = data.target

# Step 4: Preprocess the data using StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# Step 5: Prepare the model using Linear Regression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_scaled, y)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    try:
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        features = data['features']

        # Step 4: Preprocess the input data
        scaled_features = scaler.transform([features])

        # Step 7: Use the trained model for prediction
        prediction = model.predict(scaled_features)[0]

        return jsonify({'prediction': prediction})

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I am using the following script for inference

```
import requests

url = 'http://172.21.0.1:5000/predict'
data = {'features': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]}

response = requests.post(url, json=data)
prediction = response.json()['prediction']
print(f'Predicted Value: {prediction}')
```

The DAG is executing fine and I can verify that over the Airflow web UI. However, I am getting the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /predict (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000016DCBB3AB90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Please help me so that I can run the Flask server using Airflow and Docker, and use the other script to get a prediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see indicates:

> The client (your script) is trying to reach localhost (127.0.0.1) at port 5000 - and there is nothing there.

You've launched airflow inside a docker container with only port 8080 exposed to localhost. If you add a port mapping of 5000:5000 as well to your docker-compose.yml, it should work.

However, words of caution.

You are using airflow to launch a webserver (as a task) - and this task would theoretically never end, as the subprocess would simply sit wait for HTTP connections. This is not a recommended use of Airflow: even long running tasks should eventually complete.

You could simply put your flask app in a docker container of its own.

A more conventional use of Airflow would be: a task to collect a file containing (lists) features, a task to perform inference on the contents of the file. There are many permutations on this approach to meet your needs, including using a DB, etc.

Comment: I do understand this is what Airflow is intended for. However, I asked to do it this way. But thank you very much for taking your time to reply to this.